# Crear JSON con estructura propia

Tags: c#, json

Soy nuevo en esto de crear JSON, estoy tratando de crear un JSON en C# lo cual lo logro hacer pero de una manera básica es decir con la estructura básica.

Necesito obtener como resultado la siguiente estructura:

```html
{
    "Encabezado ": {
        "InstitucionId": "072",
        "FolioCliente": "A123"
    },
    "Datos": {
        "OCR": "3374999950186",
        "CIC": "",
        "ApellidoPaterno": "FLORES",
        "ApellidoMaterno": "CARLOS",
        "Nombre": "DE LA CRUZ",
        "AnioRegistro": "2008",
        "Emision": "2013",
        "ClaveElector": "LPVLJN90022109H700",
        "CURP": "LOVJ900221HDFPLN03",
        "Consentimiento": "1"
    },
    "Ubicación": {
        "PosicionSatelital ": {
            "Latitud": "13.800499",
            "Longitud": "-124.160198"
        }
    },
    "Minucias": [{
            "Tipo ": "ANSI ",
            "Nombre": "HUELLA2",
            "Valor": "145454544"
        },
        {
            "Tipo ": "ANSI ",
            "Nombre": "HUELLA7",
            "Valor": "145454544"
        }
    ]
}
```

Tengo mi codigo para el JSON:

```js
public class Validacion
    {
        public long InstitucionId { get; set; }
        public string FolioCliente { get; set; }

        public long OCR { get; set; }
        public long CIC { get; set; }
        public string ApellidoPaterno { get; set; }
        public string ApellidoMaterno { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public long AnioRegistro { get; set; }
        public long Emision { get; set; }
        public string ClaveElector { get; set; }
        public string CURP { get; set; }
        public long Consentimiento { get; set; }

        public double Latitud { get; set; }
        public double Longitud { get; set; }

        public string Tipo { get; set; }
        public string NombreMinucias { get; set; }
        public string Valor { get; set; }
        public string Tipo2 { get; set; }
        public string NombreMinucias2 { get; set; }
        public string Valor2 { get; set; }
    }
```

¿Qué tengo que agregar en mi código para poder hacer que se estructure como lo necesito?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. te recomiendo leer el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas mas el sitio. Mirando la clase que colocas tiene diferentes campos que el JSON que deseas obtener, ¿cuál es la relación entre el JSON y la clase en C# que colocas?

Comment: Es con la clase que formo mi JSON de forma básica sin la estructura que deseo

Comment: bienvenido a la hermandad de StackOverflow en español, aprovechando que tienes ganas de aprender, revisa este curso: https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/introduction-to-json-with-c-12742?l=xxtX274UB_8805494542 :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El JSON que proporcionas tiene diferentes "niveles" para agrupar la información, así que es necesario replicar esa estructura de niveles:

La manera "burda" y rápida de hacerlo es mediante [tipos **anónimos**](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types):

```
public class Validacion
{
    public object Encabezado { get; set; }
    public object Datos { get; set; }
    public object Ubicación { get; set; }
    public object[] Minucias { get; set; }
}
```

Para generarlo así:

```
Validacion jsonObject = new Validacion()
{
    Encabezado = new { InstitucionId = "072", FolioCliente = "A123" },
    Datos = new {
        OCR = "3374999950186",
        CIC = "",
        ApellidoPaterno = "FLORES",
        ApellidoMaterno = "CARLOS",
        Nombre = "DE LA CRUZ",
        AnioRegistro = 2008,
        Emision = 2013,
        ClaveElector = "LPVLJN90022109H700",
        CURP = "LOVJ900221HDFPLN03",
        Consentimiento = "1"
    },
    Ubicación = new {
        PosiciónSatelital = new {
            Latitud = 13.800499,
            Longitud = -124.160198
        }
    },
    Minucias = new object[] {
        new {
            Tipo = "ANSI ",
            Nombre = "HUELLA2",
            Valor = "145454544"
        },
        new {
            Tipo = "ANSI ",
            Nombre = "HUELLA7",
            Valor = "145454544"
        }
    }
}
```

---

La forma ***correcta*** de hacerlo es crear tus clases (o estructuras). Aquí los pongo con el sufijo `Model`:

```
public class EncabezadoModel
{
    public string InstitucionId { get; set; }
    public string FolioCliente { get; set; }
}

public class DatosModel
{
    public string OCR { get; set; }
    public string CIC { get; set; }
    public string ApellidoPaterno { get; set; }
    public string ApellidoMaterno { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int AnioRegistro { get; set; }
    public int Emision { get; set; }
    public string ClaveElector { get; set; }
    public string CURP { get; set; }
    public string Consentimiento { get; set; }
}

public class PosicionSatelitalModel
{
    public double Latitud { get; set; }
    public double Longitud { get; set; }
}

public class UbicaciónModel
{
    public PosicionSatelitalModel PosiciónSatelital { get; set; }
}

public class MinuciasModel
{
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Valor { get; set; }
}
```

Y finalmente el modelo de `Validación` quedaría así:

```
public class ValicacionModel
{
    public EncabezadoModel Encabezado { get; set; }
    public DatosModel OCR { get; set; }
    public UbicaciónModel Ubicación { get; set; }
    public List<MinuciasModel> Minucias { get; set; }
}
```

para invocarlo de esta manera:

```
ValidacionModel jsonObject = new ValidacionModel();
jsonObject.Encabezado = new EncabezadoModel()
{
    InstitucionId = "072",
    FolioCliente = "A123"
};
jsonObject.Datos = new DatosModel()
{
    OCR = "3374999950186",
    CIC = "",
    ApellidoPaterno = "FLORES",
    ApellidoMaterno = "CARLOS",
    Nombre = "DE LA CRUZ",
    AnioRegistro = 2008,
    Emision = 2013,
    ClaveElector = "LPVLJN90022109H700",
    CURP = "LOVJ900221HDFPLN03",
    Consentimiento = "1"
};
jsonObject.Ubicación = new UbicaciónModel()
{
    PosiciónSatelital = new PosicionSatelitalModel() {
        Latitud = 13.800499,
        Longitud = -124.160198
    }
};
jsonObject.Minucias = new List<MinuciasModel>();
jsonObject.Minucias.Add(new MinuciasModel()
    {
        Tipo = "ANSI ",
        Nombre = "HUELLA2",
        Valor = "145454544"
    });
jsonObject.Minucias.Add(new MinuciasModel()
    {
        Tipo = "ANSI ",
        Nombre = "HUELLA7",
        Valor = "145454544"
    });
```

Comment: Genial, salio a la perfección, mil gracias por la aportación.

Comment: Me alegro, ¿con cuál método lo hiciste? De hecho hay más maneras de escribirlo!

Comment: De la forma "correcta" fue la forma que me resulto mas fácil comprender la forma de hacerlo

Comment: muchas gracias por este ejemplo tan bien desarrollado, justo estoy armando algo similar y me ha ayudado mucho en mi intento de entender una estructura de JSON, es la primera vez que estoy tratando con este formato y la verdad es que lo veo muy interesante.

Comment: @JuanManuelPalacios Json es el futuro... no, ¡es el presente! me alegra que te sirva el ejemplo :D

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar la librería Newtonsoft.Json que puedes instalarlo a través de NuGet.

Mas o menos sería de esta forma.

```
Validacion oValidacion = new Validacion();
oValidacion.InstitucionId = "1";
oValidacion.FolioCliente = "123";
//Colocas los demás campos
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
```

No te olvides de importar

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```